# Prevent windows account from reading and editing sensitive data

Tags: windows, permissions, account

I'm trying to find a solution for a problem I'm dealing with at work. The situation is as follows:

We have a windows PC to which operators of our machine can log in to start 2 measurement applications. One of these applications is developed in house and maintained by me, the other is outsourced. Both of these applications will need to read settings, and save (sensitive) measurement data to the PC. In the current situation, operators have access to the these folders and the data within, however, we want this to only be accessible by an admin account so the operator cannot accidentally mess with the data or settings. Both of these applications have a GUI that needs to be visible to the operator. We would also preferably have these applications start at system boot, so the operator will only need to log in.

Some ideas that have been mentioned are:

**Run the applications as services.** This would take care of starting the application at boot and prevent the operator from messing with the application. However, to my findings, Windows Services cannot be GUI applications.

**Run the applications as an admin account.** This also seems like it wouldn't work, as the user who will start the application will need to know the login information of the admin account. Besides, I believe the GUI will not show up on the operators desktop, but on the admins instead.

**Make the data and setting folders read only.** This will still allow the operator to create files in the respective folders and edit these as far as I'm aware. And since the operator will start the application, the application will start with the same permissions as the operator account and thus cannot edit the existing files.

So far the only solution I have found that would definitely work is to edit the applications to remove the GUI, run these GUI-less applications as services, and develop seperate GUI applications to interface with the service. However, since this will require a lot of changes in both codebases, and one of the applications is outsourced, this would preferably be a last resort option.

Are there ways in which one of the other ideas might work? Are there any other solutions? Or is seperating the GUI from the business logic my only option?

Thanks in advance!